# (Bash) Dynamically save n arguments

Tags: bash, dynamic, arguments

I was trying to find a way to dynamically store all the arguments I would pass for a shell script in an array. This would help when I have to loop trough each and every argument, to make further use of them.

**This is the answer to my problem.**

```
#!bin/bash
#Overloop alle gegeven argumenten en sla ze op in arg(plaatsvhargument)
arr=( "$@" )

#Code om te testen of het wel werkt
y=0
while [[ $y -lt $# ]]

do

        val=${arr[$y]}
        echo $val
        (( y++))
done
```

I know i could just do this, to get each and every argument out of the array.

```
for i in ${arr[@]}
do
        echo $i    
done
```

My problem is that when I run the script i end up saving the position of an argument AND I lose one argument in the process. Example:

```
bash testscript.sh 1 2 2 3 1  gives me 2 2 3 1 (empty)
```

What am I doing wrong, and do you guys have any fixes for my issue?

Comment: Why not just do: `arr=( "$@" )` to create your array.

Comment: @anubhava, so you mean delete the whole first while loop and replace it with `arr=( "$@" ) `

Comment: @anubhava Still having a problem; I edited my question since I felt it was going the right way.

Comment: Since you're storing your args in an awway, use the length of that array to be consistent: `while [[ $y -lt ${#arr[@]} ]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
y=1
```

You should use:

```
y=0
```

since array index starts at 0 in BASH.

Also use:

```
arr=( "$@" )
```

to create your array with all the arguments passed to the script (as my comments above).

You can also loop through array elements like this in BASH:

```
for ((y=0; y<$#; y++))
do
        val="${arr[$y]}"
        echo "$val"
done
```

Comment: Looping through `"$@"` is even simpler: `for arg; do ... done`. Also you can use `${arr[y]}`.

Comment: @anubhava Changed the y to 0, but i am still missing one argument. The first one following the shell scripts name

Comment: @MrKickkiller Both the code currently in your post and this `for` loop work correctly on your sample input for me with the `y=0` change. Double check your code (add it to the post as an edit if you'd like).